# Trying to install spaCy on M2 Mac using pip:

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nlp, spacy

```
!pip install cython 
!pip install cymem
!pip install murmurhash
!pip install preshed
!pip install numpy
!pip install blis
!pip install thinc
!pip install 'spacy[apple]'
!pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
```

all of the above code works.

But when I try to run the code below

```
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

I get the following error and hence am unable to import spacy :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kyrshanlyngdoh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 188, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/Users/kyrshanlyngdoh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 147, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/Users/kyrshanlyngdoh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/Users/kyrshanlyngdoh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .errors import setup_default_warnings
  File "/Users/kyrshanlyngdoh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/errors.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .compat import Literal
  File "/Users/kyrshanlyngdoh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/compat.py", line 38, in <module>
    from thinc.api import Optimizer  # noqa: F401
  File "/Users/kyrshanlyngdoh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/thinc/api.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .initializers import normal_init, uniform_init, glorot_uniform_init, zero_init
  File "/Users/kyrshanlyngdoh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/thinc/initializers.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .backends import Ops
  File "/Users/kyrshanlyngdoh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/thinc/backends/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .mps_ops import MPSOps
  File "/Users/kyrshanlyngdoh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/thinc/backends/mps_ops.py", line 14, in <module>
    from thinc_apple_ops import AppleOps
  File "/Users/kyrshanlyngdoh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/thinc_apple_ops/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .ops import AppleOps
  File "thinc_apple_ops/ops.pyx", line 1, in init thinc_apple_ops.ops
  File "thinc_apple_ops/blas.pyx", line 1, in init thinc_apple_ops.blas
ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject
```

Answer (score 1):

In a new venv, try this:

```bash
pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
pip install 'spacy[apple]' --only-binary spacy,thinc,blis,thinc-apple-ops --no-cache-dir
```

If this works, you may want to clear your pip cache to remove incompatible cached wheels that may have been compiled from source in the past (`pip cache purge`) and then a simple `pip install 'spacy[apple]'` should work again. (There's no need to install the other dependencies individually.)

Comment: It will be slow, but try uninstalling `thinc-apple-ops`?

Comment: Ran it from terminal...thank you so much this worked! Can finally import spaCy.

Comment: It is a problem with the `thinc-apple-ops` package if you have an older version of numpy installed. We'll release an updated version soon.

Comment: I've just started coding a week ago...I'm new to anaconda,python and all of this. My research requires me to learn data cleaning and now, some NLP. So I'm learning as I go. Thanks so much!

Comment: Okay, now there is a new release of `thinc-apple-ops` and you should be able to go back to `pip install 'spacy[apple]'`.